# Keymap on region only updating from mouse click

Tags: org-mode, keymap, font-lock

I have defined some keymaps on org-mode src-blocks. If I click in the block with a mouse, I see the keymap is changed, e.g. the menu items change, and the new keybindings are active. However, if I use C-n or C-p to get into the block, the keymap is not changed. However, as soon as I edit the block, the keymap becomes active. The keymaps are added during font-lock via:

```
(add-text-properties
             beg end `(local-map ,some-key-map))))
```

inside a function that is added to org-font-lock-hook.

Is there something different about mouse motion and cursor motion that would cause this difference?

Comment: AFAIK, text property maps only depend on current point, not how it got there. How *exactly* are you testing that keybindings are active? Is this only an issue with org-src blocks? Do you have `org-src-fontify-natively` and/or `org-src-tab-acts-natively` set?

Comment: I have both of those things set to t. The test is whether the emacs menu changes to show the mode menus in the src blocks. If I click in the src block they do, and if I use keyboard navigation they don't. I have added a cursor-sensor-function that calls (org-mouse-down-mouse nil), and this makes it work whether I click or navigate in.

Answer (score 1):

What is probably happening is just that the menu is not re-computed.

You need to call `force-mode-line-update` after the cursor moves into (or out-of) the text bloc where you applied that `local-map` property.
You could do that by using something like

```
(cursor-sensor-mode 1)
...
(add-text-properties
 beg end `(local-map ,some-key-map
           cursor-sensor-functions my-csf-menu-update))))
```

along with

```
(defun my-csf-menu-update (&rest _)
  (force-mode-line-update))
```